# cannot horizontally center fixed width div in IE

Tags: html, css

I am creating a template for a website.

The example is at [Framework Login Page](http://test.webspirited.com/framework/login)
The main CSS sheet is at: [master.css](http://test.webspirited.com/framework/application/assets/css/master.css)

I am trying to center the main parent div.

I am using

```
#body {
  width: 100%;
  background: url('pathtoimage.png');
}

#inner_body{
  width: 800px;
  margin: auto;
}

<body>
  <div id="body">
    <div id="inner_body"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

What could the issue be?

Comment: HTML/CSS questions are best suited on [Doctype](http://doctype.com)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what browser you're using. Mozilla Firefox will need margin: auto; inside of the CSS (As you have now), but IE is the short-bus-rider that needs special attention...

```
#body{
 width: 100%;
 background: url('pathtoimage.png');
 **margin: auto;
 text-align: center;**
}

#inner_body{
 width: 800px;
 margin: auto;
}
.
.
.
```

For internet explorer, you have to add in text-align: center; to your css, and I noticed that you didn't have margin: auto; in the parent element that you wanted to center. Adding the simple attribute align="center" into the tag itself works in most cases.

Hope this helps!